# how apply Server.HtmlEncode for every TextBox in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many TextBox in a page.

I would like to know if there is a ways to check pro grammatically all input for this TextBox and

apply `Server.HtmlEncode` to each one.

So I do not need apply Server.HtmlEncode for every single String.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: I would like avoid User to insert malicious script to my web app

Comment: ^^ so does that mean after encoding you wish to add all the textboxes text to a collection or something?

Comment: ^^ check my answer for a sample snippet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to create a utility method for that. Something on the lines of:

Simple version if no nested text controls present:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ReturnsAllTextEnteredOnPage()
{
   Dictionary<string, string> allTextEnteredOnPage = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
   foreach (var control in Page.Controls)
   {
      if (control is TextBox)
      {
         TextBox ctrl = (TextBox)control;
         allTextEnteredOnPage.Add(ctrl.ID, Server.HtmlEncode(ctrl.Text));
      }
   }
   return allTextEnteredOnPage;
}
```

A bit complex version which considers all the textboxes present on a page:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ReturnsAllTextEnteredOnPage()
{
  Dictionary<string, string> allTextEnteredOnPage = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
  var allControls = FlattenChildren(Page);
  var allTextControls = allControls.OfType<TextBox>();
  foreach(var textCtrl in allTextControls)
  {
     allTextEnteredOnPage.Add(textCtrl.ID, Server.HtmlEncode(textCtrl.Text));
  }
  return allTextEnteredOnPage;        
}
```

The above method uses a method called FlattenChildren which can be taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209854/find-all-child-controls-of-specific-type-using-enumerable-oftypet-or-linq/2209896#2209896).

Secondly, I havent used an editor for typing that code..

Comment: can you provide any examples?

Comment: thanks you class looks good, I have not given you any downvote! thanks for your help!

Comment: ^^ thanks for accepting my answer, hope it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason for encoding the input?

Usually you would Html encode output, i.e. when you are displaying the data.

EDIT:

You might want to take a look at [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) if you want to harden your app against XSS and SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to subclass the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1xz97b.aspx) control and override the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) property to simply return an HTML-encoded string. Then you can use that control throughout your project where you need to HTML encode strings.

Alternatively, you could declare an extension method for all TextBox objects which would return an HTML-encoded version of the string, and you can simply call that extension method throughout your project instead of referring to the .Text property:

EDIT: Added extension method helper code sample

```
class TextBoxHelper{ public static string GetHtmlEncodedString(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textbox){ return Server.HtmlEncode(textbox.Text); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that if you change the values of the controls then that could cause confusion with the users (i.e. that is not what I typed). So what you could do is create a collection of sanitised inputs and use that in your application as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
             TextBox textbox = control as TextBox;
             if (textbox != null)
             {
                 values.Add(textbox.ID, Server.HtmlEncode(textbox.Text));
             }
        }        
    }
}
```

values above would then contain the santised inputs. I would also recommend looking at the [Anti-XSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) for additional protection in this type of scenario.

Comment: i do not believe, that a simple foreach will get every textbox - think of nested ones as well!