# Grid view Updatearguments does Not contain New Values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
public partial class Gridvw_expt2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   SqlCommand com;
   SqlDataAdapter da;
   DataSet ds;
   SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gj"].ConnectionString);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    com = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblExpt",con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] != null)
    {
        GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true; 
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(GridView1_RowUpdating);
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "id" };
        GridView1.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(GridView1_RowEditing);

    }
    else
        Response.Write("fkj");
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    string cls = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    string nam = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {
        e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());
    }
    com = new SqlCommand("Update tblExpt set name='" + nam + "',class='" + cls + "' where id='" + id + "'", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

}

In the above code when i try to access e.new values index out of range exception is thrown.

The table being accessed contains 3 fields id, class, name
Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Do Read This balso help u    http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/579772-gridview-update-cannot-retrieve-new-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this blog post I wrote on extracting data from gridview (and other data controls). Also, in .net 4.0 if you use 2 way binding (<# Bind("") #>) e.NewValues will be populated.

More info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/12/getting-your-data-out-of-the-data-controls.aspx

Comment: I understand the code written by u but not getting still how to implement can u help it specific to my code.    Thanks in advance

Comment: Which package to be included to use IDictonary?

Answer (score 1):

The exception you get is because row.Cells[0].Controls[0] is a DataControlLinkButton and not a TextBox. Since I don´t know the control layout of your grid you could search for your textbox instead.

Instead of:

```
int id = int.Parse(((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text);
```

do something like the code below if there is only one TextBox per row:

```
TextBox box = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First();
int id = int.Parse( box.Text );
```

If you have nested html and hierarchies check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209854/find-all-child-controls-of-specific-type-using-enumerable-oftypet-or-linq) for nested searching of controls

Comment: to get the text box OfType should be written as TextBox No?

Comment: Thanks a lot  Mikael Svenson actually i am beginner so i am getting confused. I solve it but the new Problem Is updation

Comment: You should not edit the question to be another one. Rather ask a new one, or append the second question to the original question. This way answers will reflect upon what is actually asked.