# How to find a control inside an asp.net calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, findcontrol

After adding a control in the dayrender event, is there a way to find the control later? I have tried

```
calendar.FindControl("lblSample")
```

but without success.

Here is some of my code to be more clear:

```
protected void calSample_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblSample = new Label();
    lblSample.ID = "lblSample";
    lblSample.Text = "Sample";
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(lblSample);
}
```

After the day render event and the page loads completely, I have a link button event where I try and get the control back

```
protected void lbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Not working
    Label lblSample = calSample.FindControl(lblSample);

    //Also can't get to work, this was using Ross' suggestion and the recursive find function he wrote about. I'm probably just not using it correctly.
    Label lblSample = ControlFinder.FindControl<Label>(calSample, "lblSample");
}
```

Comment: `FindControl` isn't going to recursively search, so you're going to need to make your own that searches not only the current children, but children of any containers within.

Comment: You might need to recurse through multiple layers, e.g. if your Form has a asp:Panel which has your control, you will need to navigate Form => Panel => Control.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209854/find-all-child-controls-of-specific-type-using-enumerable-oftypet-or-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is because of Ross' comment above showing me that I could use the Page.Request.Params to find the value I was after. It's not the cleanest solution but it works!

If you add a dropdownlist to a calendar control in the day render event

```
    protected void calSample_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlSample = new DropDownList();
        ddlSample.ID = "ddlSample";
        ddlSample.DataSource = sampleDS;
        ddlSample.DataBind();
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(ddlSample);
    }
```

You can get the selected value back like this, of course I need to put in more checks to verify that the dropdownlist exists, but you get the picture

```
    protected void lbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sampleID = Page.Request.Params.GetValues("ddlSample")[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because the control was not added to the page until the dayrender method - meaning you could not get a reference to it on a post back. Using the Page.Request.Params collection the OP was able to grab the value out on the postback.

---

The problem is that the find control is not recursive and the control you want is probably inside another control.

This shows you how to make a recursive find control method that would help: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/recursive-findcontrol/

Alternatively if you post the calendar controls code I can probably help you a bit more.

Ross

Comment: Thanks for the article Ross, I will use this in some of my projects. I made an edit to my question and tried to use this function for my calendar issue without success. Can you show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: ok, the issue here is that the label hasn't been added to the calendar by the time the button has been pressed. What are you actually trying to do with the label when you get a hold of it?

Comment: I was actually adding a dropdownlist in my real code and trying to retrieve the selectedvalue. I think you are right, the linkbutton event comes before the dayrender event so my controls are wiped out. I still don't know how to solve this though...

Comment: I'm trying to find a nice solution for you and I'm struggling. The best I can come up with involves inspecting the Page.Request.Params string to get the id selected... not ideal.

Comment: This solution ended up being great for me, on my save click, I just went with what you said Page.Request.Params.GetValues("ddlSample") and I got the value I needed. Do you want to submit this as an answer?

Comment: Great - you might want to make a post and mark it as an answer to close the question:-)