# Clearing all textboxes in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a number of text boxes in my page. I need to clear all text boxes after the values 
are stored. Clearing all text boxes one by one is a time taking process. Can anybody suggest me a way to clear all text boxes in single function.

Comment: Show your code here..

Comment: Run-time, compiler-time or programmer-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    tb.Text = string.Empty;
```

But this will clear the textbox which exist on the page directly, not the one inside some other controls.

Comment: i tried it but its not working.

Comment: You can turn this into a recursive-descent method to clear them all.

Comment: @ArunDev - _always_ describe "it's not working"

Comment: @ArunDev,What is not working,  its probably not clearing the nested controls of type `TextBox`, You may see this thread to find all the controls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209854/find-all-child-controls-of-specific-type-using-enumerable-oftypet-or-linq

Answer (score 1):

From the client side, using Jquery you can achieve it like this

```
$("input:text").val('');
```

This will clears values of all the text-boxes in the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you using ViewState in WebForms, then you can disable it after successful save:
    base.EnableViewState = false;